# FieldPath field names may not contain '.' in $group

Tags: mongodb

I have the following mongo data which looks like this

```
{
    eventType : "mousedown",
    eventArgs : {
        type : "touchstart",
        elementId : "id1"
    },
    creationDateTime : ISODate("2017-02-24T07:05:49.986Z")
}
```

I wrote the following query to perform group count.

```
db.analytics.aggregate
(
    {
        $match :
        {
            $and : 
            [
                {"eventArgs.type" : 'touchstart'}, 
                {eventType : 'mousedown'}, 
                {creationDateTime : {$gte : ISODate("2017-02-24T000:00:00.000Z")}}
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $group : 
        {
            _id : 
            {
                "eventsArgs.elementId" : "$elementId"
            },
            count : 
            {
                $sum : 1
            }
        }
    }
);
```

I'm getting error for `$group`, which states that

```
FieldPath field names may not contain '.'
```

If I were not able to specific '.' in

```
        $group : 
        {
            _id : 
            {
                "eventsArgs.elementId" : "$elementId"
            },
```

What is the correct way to do so?

Comment: Have your tried `"_id" :  { "eventsArgs": { "elementId" : "$eventsArgs.elementId" } },`?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't give error. However, the produced result is not desired : `{ "_id" : { "eventsArgs" : {  } }, "count" : 126311 }`. I expect to see multiple count attach with various elementId.

Comment: or simply `{ "$group": { "_id": "$eventsArgs.elementId", "count": { "$sum": 1 } } }` and then add a further `$project` pipeline to reshape the output the way you want?

Comment: But the data is quite huge (There are 500 million rows). I prefer to to filter first, before performing group by count.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng What version of mongodb are you running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have a single group field, the best way is to just use the `_id` group key on that field and then create another **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline that will reshape the `_id` key from the previous pipeline into the desired subdocument that you want. For example

```
db.analytics.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "eventArgs.type": 'touchstart', 
            "eventType": 'mousedown', 
            "creationDateTime": { "$gte": ISODate("2017-02-24T000:00:00.000Z") } 
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$eventArgs.elementId",
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "eventsArgs.elementId": "$_id",
            "count": 1, "_id": 0
        }
    }
]);
```

The following should work as well:

```
db.analytics.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "eventArgs.type": 'touchstart', 
            "eventType": 'mousedown', 
            "creationDateTime": { "$gte": ISODate("2017-02-24T000:00:00.000Z") } 
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
               "eventArgs": {
                   "elementId": "$eventArgs.elementId"
               }
            },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
]);
```